# Is it possible join cells of NSGridView in Interface Builder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, gridview, interface-builder

I saw answers how to set different count of columns in rows to `NSGridView` programmatically. Like this:

```
 ______________
|       |      |
|  cell | cell |
|_______|______|
|    |    |    |
|cell|cell|cell|
|____|____|____|
|              |
|     cell     |
|______________|
```

But I cannot find a way do the same in Storyboard. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  Select the cells you would like to merge.

Click the disclosure button in the column/row header and select 'Merge'

[image]